# Identifying continuous stay using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help with identifying continuous stay based on dates and site name. For example for the sample below -

```
Name    Start_Dt    End_Dt          Site 
A       2015-01-07  2015-01-31      TSS 
A       2015-02-01  2015-02-28      TSS 
A       2015-03-01  2015-03-14      TSS 
A       2015-03-21  2015-03-31      TSS 
A       2015-04-01  2015-04-11      TSS
```

Expected Output:

```
Name    Start_Dt    End_Dt          Site 
A       2015-01-07  2015-03-14      TSS 
A       2015-03-21  2015-04-11      TSS
```

If possible I would like to assign stay id to the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to identify where periods of adjacent stays start.  You can do this with a `left join` to see if the previous stay ends on the day before.

Then, accumulating this flag over all the day provides a grouping mechanism for identifying the groups of adjacent stays.  With this information the rest is just aggregation:

```
select name, site, min(start_dt), max(end_dt)
from (select t.*, (case when t2.site is null then 1 else 0 end) as startFlag,
             (@cnt := if(@s = site, @cnt + (case when t2.site is null then 1 else 0 end),
                         if(@s := site, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from t left join
           t t2
           on t2.site = t.site and
              t2.end_dt = date_sub(t.start_dt, interval 1 day) cross join
           (select @s := '', @cnt := 0) params
      order by site, start_dt
     ) t
group by name, site, grp
```

Comment: I am sorry I am quite new to MySql hence having trouble to understand the query here. Can you please explain why there is a cross join. Also I am getting a syntax error for the line  (@cnt := if(@s := site, @cnt + (case when t2.site is null then 0 else 1 end). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks again for taking the time to respond. I executed the query but I am always getting one record as output. On executing the sub query that is - select t.*, (case when t2.site is null then 0 else 1 end) as startFlag, (@cnt := if(@s := t.site, @cnt + (case when t2.site is null then 0 else 1 end), if(@s := t2.site, 1, 1))) as grp ........ order by site, start_dt, I am getting the output as following    -

Comment: Name Start_Dt End_Dt   Site startFlag grp                  A 2015-01-07  2015-01-31  TSS 0 1
A 2015-02-01  2015-02-28  TSS 1 1
A 2015-03-01 2015-03-14  TSS 1 1
A 2015-03-21  2015-03-31 TSS 0 1
A 2015-04-01 2015-04-11  TSS 1 1

Comment: the grp variable count is not incrementing

Comment: @user5104018 . . . The first `if()` should have `=` not `:=`.

Comment: thanks for your time. tried adding not, (@cnt :=  if(@s <> t.site, @cnt + (case when t2.site is null then 0 else 1 end), if(@s := t.site, 1, 1))) as grp, but not getting the expected output. It is returing 3 records                                                 A TSS 2015-01-07 00:00:00 2015-04-11 00:00:00
A TSS 2015-02-01 00:00:00 2015-02-28 00:00:00
A TSS 2015-03-01 00:00:00 2015-03-14 00:00:00

Comment: Very sorry about misinterpreting your comment! I changed (@cnt := if(@s = t.site, @cnt + (case when t2.site is null then 0 else 1 end), if(@s := t2.site, 1, 1))) as grp, but still unable to get the grp increment correctly!

Comment: The output that I am getting is                                                                    A TSS 2015-02-01  2015-02-28 
A TSS 2015-03-01  2015-03-14
A TSS 2015-01-07  2015-04-11

Comment: I am able to follow the left join, but unable to understand why we need the cross join. If possible can you please explain how the cross join (select @s := '', @cnt := 0) works with the left join to achieve the expected output. Thanks again

Comment: @user5104018 . . . The cross join is simply a mechanism for initializing the parameters within a query.  Otherwise, you need to do that with separate statements.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. I tried without the cross join by resetting the variables at the start of the query and the result is same as with the cross join. Any thoughts on how to get the grp variable to increment correctly.

Comment: I am getting the following output for the inner query -                                      Name  Start_Dt End_Dt Site startFlag              grp
A 2015-01-07 2015-01-31  TSS  0   1
A 2015-02-01 2015-02-28  TSS  1   1
A 2015-03-01 2015-03-14  TSS  1   2
A 2015-03-21 2015-03-31  TSS  0   1
A 2015-04-01 2015-04-11  TSS  1   3                             As you can see the grp is incrementing for the 3 rd record, but it should be 1 for the first 3 records and the last 2 records as 2, right?

Comment: If possible can you please explain the use of second if  - if(@s := t.site, 1, 1). I have to extend the query to check on more than on variable that is both name and site, however though I do not get a syntax error mySql seems to assign only the second variable. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: The first `if()` checks if the site is the same.  If so, it increments the `@grp` values for the site.  The second starts over for a new site.  The `:=` is a way of assigning the variable.  (The use of variables should all be in a single expression, which is why this uses nested `if()`s for this purpose.)

Comment: So if I need to assign a new site and name (since the name and site uniquely identify a record in the entire data set), is it possible? Please let me know. I tried this with 2nd if (if((@n := name and @s := site)) but mySql takes for the second variable only and always assigns a 1 for the variable @n. Thanks again for all the help, I think I have come a long way from the time since I started, though I don't have the exact output yet. Will keep trying!

Comment: @user5104018 . . . I sometimes do this using `concat_ws()`.

Comment: can you please give an example on how to use this function in assigning two or more variables within if statement. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gordon - would you have a solution for this please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406615/identify-customer-visits-occurring-after-a-given-time-period-in-mysql

Comment: Hi Gordon - for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406615/identify-customer-visits-occurring-after-a-given-time-period-in-mysql - should a stored procedure be used since applying the same logic of left join fails due to the requirement of always having to check each visit date of a customer against only the record that meets the condition of previous 45 day visit. Thanks.