# Identify customer visits occurring after a given time period in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to identify customer visits occurring 45 days using mysql. 1st visit of the customer must be selected, the following visits which occur 45 days after the previously selected visit must be selected. For example,  I have the below sample visits table -

```
Visit_ID    Cust_ID Vst_Beg_Dt  Vst_End_Dt  Post_45_Day_Dt  Selection Criteria
121         678     2015-07-02  2015-07-08  8/22/2015       select since it is the first visit
223         678     2015-10-25  2015-10-27  12/11/2015      select since the visit occurs after 45 days -  8/22/2015
229         678     2016-02-21  2016-02-23  4/8/2016        select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015
445         545     2015-11-23  2015-11-28  1/12/2016       select since it is the first visit
198         545     2016-01-07  2016-01-12  2/26/2016       not selected since the visit is not after 45 days
271         545     2016-01-19  2016-01-29  3/14/2016       select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015
841         291     2015-09-08  2015-09-12  10/27/2015      select since it is the first visit
987         291     2015-12-19  2015-12-23  2/6/2016        select since the visit occurs after 45 days - 10/27/2015
211         291     2015-12-26  2016-01-06  2/20/2016       not selected since the visit is not after 45 days
122         291     2016-02-25  2016-02-27  4/12/2016       select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 2/6/2016
```

The expected output must have only the following records -

```
Visit_ID    Cust_ID Vst_Beg_Dt  Vst_End_Dt      
121         678     2015-07-02  2015-07-08      
223         678     2015-10-25  2015-10-27      
229         678     2016-02-21  2016-02-23      
445         545     2015-11-23  2015-11-28      
271         545     2016-01-19  2016-01-29      
841         291     2015-09-08  2015-09-12      
987         291     2015-12-19  2015-12-23      
122         291     2016-02-25  2016-02-27
```

Is this possible? I am running into issues to identify the previous visit when the customer has more than 2 visits. Thanks!

Comment: Mihai - Thanks so much for the edits!

Answer (score 0):

test this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT cv.*
  , CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 45 DAY) >= Vst_Beg_Dt AND Cust_ID = @c THEN @d
    WHEN DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 45 DAY) < Vst_Beg_Dt AND Cust_ID = @c THEN @d := Vst_End_Dt
    WHEN (@c := Cust_ID) AND (@d := Vst_End_Dt) THEN @d END AS end45
  FROM customer_visits AS cv, (SELECT @d := CURDATE(), @c := 0) AS p 
  ORDER BY Cust_ID, Vst_Beg_Dt ) part_by_End_Dt45
WHERE Vst_End_Dt = end45
ORDER BY Cust_ID DESC, Vst_Beg_Dt ASC;
```

Subquery do partitioning, store first Vst_End_Dt date for current cust_id in variable @d, if Vst_Beg_Dt > @d + 45 or cust_id changed then again set @d = Vst_End_Dt. Value of @d is returned in end45.
Final query filter end45 = Vst_End_Dt, so if Vst_End_Dt <> @d row is spiked.

**EDIT:**
I don't know what you expect more, this query return result exactly like posted by you.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6688c/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_visits
    ( Visit_ID        INT
  , Cust_ID         INT
  , Vst_Beg_Dt      DATE
  , Vst_End_Dt      DATE
  , Post_45_Day_Dt  DATE
  , Selection_Criteria VARCHAR(90))
;

INSERT INTO customer_visits
    (Visit_ID, Cust_ID, Vst_Beg_Dt, Vst_End_Dt, Post_45_Day_Dt, Selection_Criteria)
VALUES
  (121, 678, '2015-07-02', '2015-07-08', '2015-08-22', 'select since it is the first visit'),
  (223, 678, '2015-10-25', '2015-10-27', '2015-12-11', 'select since the visit occurs after 45 days - 8/22/2015'),
  (229, 678, '2016-02-21', '2016-02-23', '2016-04-08', 'select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015'),
  (445, 545, '2015-11-23', '2015-11-28', '2016-01-12', 'select since it is the first visit'),
  (198, 545, '2016-01-07', '2016-01-12', '2016-02-26', 'not selected since the visit is not after 45 days'),
  (271, 545, '2016-01-19', '2016-01-29', '2016-03-14', 'select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015'),
  (841, 291, '2015-09-08', '2015-09-12', '2015-10-27', 'select since it is the first visit'),
  (987, 291, '2015-12-19', '2015-12-23', '2016-02-06', 'select since the visit occurs after 45 days - 10/27/2015'),
  (211, 291, '2015-12-26', '2016-01-06', '2016-02-20', 'not selected since the visit is not after 45 days'),
  (122, 291, '2016-02-25', '2016-02-27', '2016-04-12', 'select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 2/6/2016')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Visit_ID
, Cust_ID
, DATE_FORMAT(Vst_Beg_Dt, '%Y-%m-%d') as Beg_Dt
, DATE_FORMAT(Vst_End_Dt, '%Y-%m-%d') as End_Dt
, Selection_Criteria
FROM (
  SELECT cv.*
  , CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 45 DAY) >= Vst_Beg_Dt AND Cust_ID = @c THEN @d
    WHEN DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 45 DAY) < Vst_Beg_Dt AND Cust_ID = @c THEN @d := Vst_End_Dt
    WHEN (@c := Cust_ID) AND (@d := Vst_End_Dt) THEN @d END AS end45
  FROM customer_visits AS cv, (SELECT @d := CURDATE(), @c := 0) AS p 
  ORDER BY Cust_ID, Vst_Beg_Dt ) part_by_End_Dt45
WHERE Vst_End_Dt = end45
ORDER BY Cust_ID DESC, Vst_Beg_Dt ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6688c/3/0)**:

```
| Visit_ID | Cust_ID |     Beg_Dt |     End_Dt |                                                                        Selection_Criteria |
|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      121 |     678 | 2015-07-02 | 2015-07-08 |                                                        select since it is the first visit |
|      223 |     678 | 2015-10-25 | 2015-10-27 |                                   select since the visit occurs after 45 days - 8/22/2015 |
|      229 |     678 | 2016-02-21 | 2016-02-23 | select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015 |
|      445 |     545 | 2015-11-23 | 2015-11-28 |                                                        select since it is the first visit |
|      271 |     545 | 2016-01-19 | 2016-01-29 | select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 12/11/2015 |
|      841 |     291 | 2015-09-08 | 2015-09-12 |                                                        select since it is the first visit |
|      987 |     291 | 2015-12-19 | 2015-12-23 |                                  select since the visit occurs after 45 days - 10/27/2015 |
|      122 |     291 | 2016-02-25 | 2016-02-27 |   select since the visit occurs after 45 days of the previously selected visit - 2/6/2016 |
```

Comment: No, this isn't working. Can you please explain the approach you are trying to solve. Thanks!

Comment: This query is bringing only the first visit for each of the customer. So for the above sample data only 3 records are fetched. Why is the d variable reset to curdate?

Comment: resetting to curdate is I thing not right because the comparison has to happen between subsequent visits of the same customer.

Comment: Can this accomplished using sql query or a stored procedure must be used? Can someone help?

Comment: this is sql query, and return result posted by you, what you expect?